# Custom (manual) implementation of MSAA in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan, antialiasing

Im using Vulkan to render simple textured meshes. To achieve a smooth result, I tried to use the built-in multisampling, but the maximum available number of samples for the render target (image) is only `x4`. This is not enough for my purposes, I need `x8/x16`.

How to efficiently implement antialiasing manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multisample antialiasing is a technique that requires cooperation from the rasterizer, render targets, and other portions of the per-fragment processing hardware. It's a technique that rasterizes at a higher resolution, but only executes the fragment shader at a lower resolution, broadcasting the results across multiple samples within the same pixel area.

That's not something you can do manually.

You can always resort to super-sampling (render at a high resolution and then downsample). Or you can use faux antialiasing techniques like FXAA and the like. But you can't emulate MSAA manually.